# Add a graph showing number of reviews over time

Tags: feature-request, review, election

From looking at the Reviews tab on the user profile, it is quite difficult to see the activity of reviews over time.

This isn't normally an issue, but say that someone is participating in an Election - it would be very useful for looking to see if someone is suddenly doing lots more reviews - something can be hard to see just from a list of dates.